# Can you add more than one modifier to vue js v-model?

Tags: vue.js

Can you add more than one modifier?

For example:

```html
<input v-model.trim="name.first"/>
<input v-model.lazy="name.first"/>
```

into something along the line

```html
<input v-model.{lazy,trim}="name.first"/>
```

Possible or not possible?
Yes!

followup question:
What is the concept behind it?
I understand it works,
but ".lazy.trim" sounds like trim is a part of lazy object

Comment: like `v-model.trim.lazy`? yep

Comment: Why don't you just try it anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,we can add more than one modifier to Vue js v-model.

```js
new Vue({
  'el': '#app',
  data: {
    val: 'default value',
    num: 0,
    trimExample: ''
  },
  methods: {
    handleBtnClick() {
      console.log(this.trimExample, this.num)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

  <input type="text" v-model.lazy="val">
  <br> {{val}}

  <br><br>
  <input type="text" v-model.number="num">
  <input type="text" v-model.trim.lazy="trimExample">
  <button v-on:click="handleBtnClick">
check console
</button>

</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/shvmbisht/bqLk6uty/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it !
for example you can see this link which v-model.trim.lazy is used in it !

https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form

```
<input class="form__input" v-model.trim.lazy="$v.age.$model"/>
```